# How do I catch a hasNextInt() String input exception?

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

In my java app, which is a simple TollMachine simulator, I must implement the try/catch code in my code. I managed to work around the String input on a hasNextInt prompt, but when I try doing the same using try/catch, I just can't get the program to go into the catch section. The program goes into an infinite loop as it is, and I really need to get it to work with the try/catch method. Otherwise, I used an if(hasNextInt)/else(workaround) to get rid of the string input and prevent the infinite loop.

```
public class TollMachine {

    static boolean running = true;  //variable to control whether the program should run
    static int userInput = -1;           //variable to store the user's input
    static String userInput2 = "";  //variable to store the input in case user does not enter an integer
    static int motoTicketCount = 0; //variable to store the number of tickets sold(moto)
    static int carTicketCount = 0;  //variable to store the number of tickets sold(car)
    static int vanTicketCount = 0;  //variable to store the number of tickets sold(van)
    static int truckTicketCount = 0;//variable to store the number of tickets sold(truck)
    static int totalTicketCount = 0;//variable to store the number of total tickets sold
    static Scanner keyb = new Scanner(System.in);   //variable to detect the user's input

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        while (userInput != 0) //runs while userInput != 0
        {

            //This is the main menu, the user is prompted to choose an option
            System.out.println("1. Motorcycle");
            System.out.println("2. Car");
            System.out.println("3. Van");
            System.out.println("4. Truck");
            System.out.println("5. Display total tickets sold.");
            System.out.println("0. Exit");

            try {

                if (keyb.hasNextInt())  //checks whether the user inputs an integer
                {

                    userInput = keyb.nextInt(); //stores the user's input to the userInput

                    if (userInput > 5 || userInput < 0)    //if one of these conditions are true, the user selected an option
                    {                                   //that is not mentioned
                        System.out.println("Invalid input.");   //displays the Invalid input error
                    } else {
                        //checks which option the user chose with multiple "if" conditions
                        if (userInput == 1) {
                            //Displays an appropriate message to the user, and increases the two counters by 1
                            System.out.println("Here is your motorcycle ticket.");
                            motoTicketCount++;
                            totalTicketCount++;
                        }
                        if (userInput == 2) {
                            //Displays an appropriate message to the user, and increases the two counters by 1
                            System.out.println("Here is your car ticket.");
                            carTicketCount++;
                            totalTicketCount++;
                        }
                        if (userInput == 3) {
                            //Displays an appropriate message to the user, and increases the two counters by 1
                            System.out.println("Here is your van ticket.");
                            vanTicketCount++;
                            totalTicketCount++;
                        }
                        if (userInput == 4) {
                            //Displays an appropriate message to the user, and increases the two counters by 1   
                            System.out.println("Here is your truck ticket.");
                            truckTicketCount++;
                            totalTicketCount++;
                        }
                        if (userInput == 5) {
                            //Displays how many of each ticket were sold, and the total number of tickets sold
                            System.out.println("Motorcycle tickets sold: " + motoTicketCount);
                            System.out.println("Car tickets sold: " + carTicketCount);
                            System.out.println("Van tickets sold: " + vanTicketCount);
                            System.out.println("Truck tickets sold: " + truckTicketCount);
                            System.out.println("Total tickets sold: " + totalTicketCount);
                        }
                        if (userInput == 0) {
                            running = false;    //terminates the program
                        }
                    }//end of else after the if (hasNextInt())

                }//end of first if (hasNextInt())                                         

            }//end of try

            catch (Exception e)    //this SHOULD catch an invalid input error
            {
                System.out.println("Invalid input.");  //displays invalid input in case the
                userInput2 = keyb.next();              //discard the bad input
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "running = false;    //terminates the program" it doesn't. The fact that `userInput == 0` would break the loop; `running` is irrelevant.

Comment: You should place the catch outside the loop, that way you don't have to break it artificially.

Comment: @AndyTurner you are correct, its just a comment I forgot to erase as I did use a running bool earlier

Comment: @PeterLawrey wouldn't that break the loop in case of an exception ?

Comment: @dotstream indeed. You get an exception when you can't read any more data.

Comment: that solves my second question, cause it did seem like it wouldn't throw an exception but I wasn't sure why! Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In here:

```
                if (userInput >5 || userInput<0)    //if one of these conditions are true, the user selected an option
                {                                   //that is not mentioned
                    System.out.println("Invalid input.");   //displays the Invalid input error
                }
```

Change the `System.out.println...` to `Throw new Exception("Invalid input.");`

Note: this isn't really the correct use of an exception, but it may help you understand it.

in your catch block:

```
catch(Exception ex){
    System.out.println(ex.toString());
}
```

EDIT: To try to understand the concept of the exception I would encourage you to try to change your input check to `if(keyb.hasNext())` and then trying to cast the input to an integer with `Integer.parseInt(keyb.next());` in your try block and catching the resultant `NumberFormatException`.

Also, rather than using the `userInput2` variable to store the erroneous data you can just set `userInput = -1;` to restart the loop in your catch function.

Full code:

```
public class TollMachine 
{

static boolean running = true;  //variable to control whether the program should run
static int userInput = -1;           //variable to store the user's input
static String userInput2 = "";  //variable to store the input in case user does not enter an integer
static int motoTicketCount = 0; //variable to store the number of tickets sold(moto)
static int carTicketCount = 0;  //variable to store the number of tickets sold(car)
static int vanTicketCount = 0;  //variable to store the number of tickets sold(van)
static int truckTicketCount = 0;//variable to store the number of tickets sold(truck)
static int totalTicketCount = 0;//variable to store the number of total tickets sold
static Scanner keyb = new Scanner(System.in);   //variable to detect the user's input

public static void main(String[] args)
{

    while (userInput != 0) //runs while userInput != 0
    {

        //This is the main menu, the user is prompted to choose an option
        System.out.println("1. Motorcycle");
        System.out.println("2. Car");
        System.out.println("3. Van");
        System.out.println("4. Truck");
        System.out.println("5. Display total tickets sold.");
        System.out.println("0. Exit");

        try
        {
            /**
            THIS THROWS YOUR EXCEPTION
            **/
            if (keyb.hasNext())  
            {

                userInput = Interger.parseInt(keyb.next()); //stores the user's input to the userInput

                if (userInput >5 || userInput<0)    //if one of these conditions are true, the user selected an option
                {                                   //that is not mentioned
                    System.out.println("Invalid input.");   //displays the Invalid input error
                }
                else
                {
                    //checks which option the user chose with multiple "if" conditions
                    if (userInput == 1)
                    {

                        //Displays an appropriate message to the user, and increases the two counters by 1
                        System.out.println("Here is your motorcycle ticket.");
                        motoTicketCount++;   
                        totalTicketCount++;

                    }
                    if (userInput == 2)
                    {

                        //Displays an appropriate message to the user, and increases the two counters by 1
                        System.out.println("Here is your car ticket.");
                        carTicketCount++;
                        totalTicketCount++;

                    }
                    if (userInput == 3)
                    {

                        //Displays an appropriate message to the user, and increases the two counters by 1
                        System.out.println("Here is your van ticket.");
                        vanTicketCount++;
                        totalTicketCount++;

                    }
                    if (userInput == 4)
                    {

                        //Displays an appropriate message to the user, and increases the two counters by 1   
                        System.out.println("Here is your truck ticket.");
                        truckTicketCount++;
                        totalTicketCount++;

                    }
                    if (userInput == 5)
                    {

                        //Displays how many of each ticket were sold, and the total number of tickets sold
                        System.out.println("Motorcycle tickets sold: "+motoTicketCount);
                        System.out.println("Car tickets sold: "+carTicketCount);
                        System.out.println("Van tickets sold: "+vanTicketCount);
                        System.out.println("Truck tickets sold: "+truckTicketCount);
                        System.out.println("Total tickets sold: "+totalTicketCount);

                    }
                    if (userInput == 0)
                    {

                        running = false;    //terminates the program

                    }
                }//end of else after the if (hasNextInt())

             }//end of first if (hasNextInt())                                         

        }//end of try

        catch (NumberFormatException e)    //this SHOULD catch an invalid input error
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid input.");  //displays invalid input in case the
            userInput = -1;
        }

    }

}



}
```

At work, so if what I gave you is super broken its because I can't compile and test right now. But this should give you the right idea.

Comment: this seems to work other than a tiny grammar mistake (Interger instead of Integer) but thank you a lot! Unfortunately for me, this might not be allowed in my application as I'm a college student and we're supposed to use what they've taught us. Anyways, thank you for the quick reply and the solution!

Comment: Totally understand if you can't use the solution. I was just trying to offer something to help illustrate exception throwing as much as anything else. Good luck in school!